# Get value of static variables in inline functions?

Tags: c, static, inline

May be my question is a little bit silly, but I can't get this code to work correctly. I have read similar question with answers, but there were a little bit different situation.

So, the question is: "Is it possible to get static variable value in inline functions?"

I code the program for microcontroller with small amount of memory and low speed. For some reason I need to make some functions inline (to save memory and time of execution).
This is the problem description:

For example, I have three files in my program: `main.c`, `some.h`, `some.c` .

In `some.c`:

```
#include "some.h"
static int foo;

[... other functions that uses "foo"]
```

In `some.h`:

```
#ifndef SOME_H_
#define SOME_H_
    static int foo;

    inline int __attribute__((always_inline))
    get_foo(void){
        return foo;
    }
#endif
```

In `main.c`:

```
#include "some.h"
int bar;
int main(void){
   bar = get_foo();
   return bar;
}
```

When I tried to compile, I'm getting following:

```
warning: 'foo' is static but used in inline function 'get_foo' which is not static
```

When I tried to put `extern static int foo;` to `some.h`, I got:

```
error: multiple storage classes in declaration specifiers
error: static declaration of 'foo' follows non-static declaration
```

I need to get values of "static" variables from external file in "inline" functions. I want to keep them "static" to separate from main code, as local variable. Is it a way to do this correctly?

Thank you in advance!

**EDIT:**

To be more clear:  I need to get the the value of a variable in one file (`some.c`) in another file (`main.c`) by inline function. If the function `get_foo()` is NOT "inline", everything works perfect, but it takes more memory and execution time.

Comment: A sidenote, `static` in C-context is meant for linkage.

Comment: @sjsam *A sidenote, `static` in C-context is meant for linkage.*  Not always.  `static` can also be used to define the storage duration of a variable.  Per **6.2.4  Storage durations of objects** of [the C Standard](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg14/www/docs/n1570.pdf):  An  object  has  a
*storage 
duration*
that  determines  its  lifetime.   There  are  four  storage
durations:  static,  thread,  automatic,  and  allocated.   Allocated  storage  is  described  in
7.22.3.

Comment: static as *duration* only occurs in function body. @AndrewHenle

Comment: @AndrewHenle : Not always. yeah :-)

Comment: @PaulStelian :`occurs in block scope` is more correct.

Comment: In addition to the advice in the answers below, you probably want to define `get_foo` as `static inline int __attribute__((always_inline)) get_foo(void) { return foo; }`, otherwise you may be defining an externally linked `get_foo` several times in addition to the inlined definitions.

Comment: @Ian Abbott : Thank you for you comment. I have tried to add `static` to `inline int __attribute__((always_inline)) get_foo(void)`, but it returns always `0`, because it creates new variable every time, I guess.

Comment: @cyclone125 If you want all the inline instances of `get_foo` from different compilation units to access the same variable (not different variables in each compilation unit with the same name), that variable will need to have external linkage.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your request for inlining is in some way incompatible with the internal linkage of the variable.

You have a static variable which means that this variable is only visible in that file.

On the other you have an inline function. If this function would be inlined somewhere else than in this file, then it would refer to another foo variable, which is probably not what you want; at least the compiler warns you about it. It suggests you to change the visibility of that function to static, as to only be available in the same entity than foo.

In another try, you add extern, but this is incompatible with static visibility, choose, extern or static. Read about linkage and visibility rules in C language, for more information.

You also suggest to add foo in some header, which is not a good idea, headers are reserved for declaration of objects not definition. You are encouraged to add type definition in headers, external declaration of objects; but discouraged from define objects (while not strictly forbidden, this would too often lead to clashes).

Comment: Thank you for your answer. That's why I am asking. So, there is no way to get value from static variable form one file (`some.h`) to another (`main.c`) in inline function? I need this, because if this function is not inline, the compiler creates a subroutine in assembler, with CALL, READ RAM, RET, but I want it to compile it inline (no subroutine, no CALL and RET, just READ RAM).

Comment: Is it a requirement that your variable be static?

Comment: Hmm, I declared variable static in order to be visible only inside `some.c`. I'm going to use this files (`some.h` and `some.c`) as a library with other programs in future, so I'd like to keep them local in their files (not visible for main program), and get the value from functions.

Comment: Then you'll have to pay the price for hiding things, their access will cost you slightly more.

Comment: Ok, I understand. I thought, may be there is a way to do this somehow. Anyway, thanks for an answer! I appreciate it.

Answer (score 2):

In this case, `static` means the variable foo will be a different foo in each source file. If you change `static int foo;` to `extern int foo;` in the header and then have a single `int foo;` in one .c file, I think the compiler warning will go away and your inline function will work fine.

At file scope, `static` hides a name from the linker so you effectively have different variables in each file.

`extern static int foo;` is just a mistake. It means, there is something called foo in some other file that I want you to link to, but the name is hidden.  The compiler is just saying "forget it".

Comment: `variable foo will be a different foo in each source file`. Well, a separate variable per translation unit might actually be the intention here..

Comment: op said "I need to get values of "static" variables from external file in "inline" functions."  I took that to mean he wants to get the the value of a variable in one file (the external one) in another file. Not possible if the variable is static.

Comment: @evatil : You're right ("I took that to mean he wants to get the the value of a variable in one file (the external one) in another file."). So, this is not possible for static variable, right? Bit if I make it "not static", it wil not be "local", and it's possible to redefine it by mistake in other file?

Comment: You're probably getting confused by the meaning of the word `static`. `static` in Java and C mean two very different things.

Answer (score 1):

There is no point for defining a static variable in a header file. Every time you include that header file you will get a new fresh copy of the variable...

Why you don't just define it as

```
extern int foo;
```

This way you will have the variable available from any source that included the header

Comment: Thank you for you answer! Do you mean, to define `int foo;` in `some.h`, and `extern int foo;` in `main.c`? As global variable?

Comment: no, you have to define int foo; in some.c and extern int foo; in some.h
Then, in main.c (and any other c file where you want to have access to foo), you include some.h

Comment: The pre-processor will add the included file to the c file just like copy/paste would do (so the 'extern int foo;' line will be added to it) and when the compiler compiles main.c it will understand, thanks to the 'extern' property, that foo variable is defined in other c file so it will be the linker job to address it

Answer (score 0):

If you want to have your variable `static` in a specific translation unit, an `inline` function that would "live" in another translation unit would never be able to access this `static` object. That is why access to `static` objects from `inline` functions is not allowed, the semantics of what that would mean is simply not clear.

You can either define an `extern` function that provides the value of its TU where it is defined, or `static` function(s) with different instantiations in every TU that provide just the value, there.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. That's why I am asking. I need this, because if this function is not inline, the compiler creates a subroutine in assembler, with CALL, READ RAM, RET, but I want it to compile it inline (no subroutine, no CALL and RET, just READ RAM). Can you explain you suggestions with `extern` function or `static` function? I have tried to make something like `static inline int __attribute__((always_inline)) get_foo(void){ return foo; }` , but it returns always `0`, because it creates separate variable, I guess.

Comment: You really have a semantical problem, here. An `inline` function in a different TU can't access an object for which, by definition, it knows nothing about. So either you share your variable from the start, have it visible through the linker or you don't share it, but then you need an accessor function that is shared through the linker.